# ctr run equality mapping for docker run

Tags: docker, containerd

Where can find the ctr run equality mapping for docker run?
For example,
https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

How can I map the --hostname and -p parameters?
I can use ctr like:

```
ctr run -d --net-host docker.io/library/rabbitmq:3-management some-rabbit
```

But I can't find directly mapping in ctr for --hostname and -p.
Is there a reference here?